# Passing a char pointer array to a function

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have written following sample code to demonstrate my problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void f (char*** a)
{
    *a = new (char*[2]);
    *a[0] = new char[10];
    *a[1] = new char[10];
    strcpy(*a[0], "abcd");
    strcpy(*a[1],"efgh");
}

int main ()
{
    char** b = NULL;
    f(&b);
    cout<<b[0]<<"\n";
    cout<<b[1]<<"\n";
    return 1;
}
```

In this code i found that *a = new (char*[2]); not allocating memory of *a[1].

In gdb i am getting following seg fault.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400926 in f (a=0x7fffffffdfe8) at array1.cpp:10
10          *a[1] = new char[10];
(gdb) p *a[1]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

This is really confusing me. Can someone explain where i am going wrong.

I know i can pass argument like void f (char**& a) and by calling function f(b) and this works . But i want to know want happening if i use char*** a. It should also work. Sorry if this is an stupid question.
Any tutorial or reference on above problem will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I sure hope this is just a more or less academic question and that you are using `std::vector<std::string>` et al in production code... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), where the array-indexing operator `[]` have higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.

So the expression `*a[0]` is really, from the compilers point of view, the same as `*(a[0])`, which is not what you want.

You have to explicitly add parentheses to change the precedence:

```
(*a)[0] = ...
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void f (char*** a)
{
  
    *a = new (char*[2]);
    (*a)[0] = new char[10];
    (*a)[1] = new char[10];
    strcpy((*a)[0], "Saurab");
    strcpy((*a)[1],"srivastav");
}

int main ()
{
    char** b = NULL;
    f(&b);
    cout<<b[0]<<"\n";
    cout<<b[1]<<"\n";
    return 1;
}
Now its working.

Comment: Actually `*a[0]` works because it is correct!  `*a[0]` and `(*a)[0]` are both `a[0][0]` - it makes no difference to swap the zeroes around.  Cf. `*a[1] == a[1][0]` but `(*a)[1] == a[0][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

a[0], a[1] are char, and they have a value in them, dereferencing that value will obviously cause a segmentation fault. What you may want to do is:

```
(*a)[...]
```

dereference 'a' which is a pointer, this will give u an array.